# How to change the font color of a variable in whole input cell

Tags: front-end, string-manipulation, cells, display, boxes

I want to track the occurrence of a particular variable in a code. So the idea is to change its color. Usually I do it in a crude way - convert the code into text and then use `StringReplace`. For example say this is my code,

```
c = k;
p = a x + b y + c z;
q = b x + c y + a z;
r = c x + a y + b z;
```

and I want to track the variable `b` and `c`. So this is what I do

```
var1 = "c"; col1 = Red;
var2 = "b"; col2 = Blue;
StringReplace[
" 
c=k;
p=a x +b y +c z;
q=b x+c y +a z;
r=c x+ a y+b z;
",
{var1 -> Style[var1, Bold, col1],
 var2 -> Style[var2, Bold, col2]}
]
```

[image]

Not very neat, but does the job. And I can't get rid of the `~` when I use `Style`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this to create a functionality which will fit your need the best.

Here's how you can preview your input cell with `c` highlighted `Red`.

```
CellPrint[
 NotebookRead @ PreviousCell[] /. 
  "c" -> InterpretationBox[
           StyleBox["c", FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
           c
         ] 
]
```

[image]

You can even evaluate such cell.

---

#### General solution

works quite well, based on pallete but you can put it as a shortcut ofc:

```
(*first evaluate `panel` definition, it is at the bottom for post readability*)

CreatePalette[
  Button["CellHighlight",
   Module[{cell = Quiet[First@SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]]]},
    If[MatchQ[cell, _CellObject], 
     CreateDialog[panel[cell]], 
     Print["select the cell first"]]
    ],
   Method -> "Queued", 
   ImageSize -> (3 CurrentValue["DefaultButtonSize"][[;; , 1]])
]
  ] /. DownValues[panel]
```

#### usage

select cell and click the button on palette:

[image]

For cases like yours it you will get fully functional code. For more complex cases, with some scoping structures, I don't know. But looks nice ;)

[image]

#### ToDo

- better pattern for extracting valid symbol names
- additional directives

#### panel definition

```
panel[cell_] := 
 DynamicModule[{color, rule, highlight, data, content, symbols},

  data = NotebookRead@cell;

  content = data[[1]];

  symbols = 
   Union@Cases[content, 
     s_String /; 
      StringMatchQ[
       s, _?LowerCaseQ ~~ LetterCharacter ...], \[Infinity]];
  color[_] = RGBColor[0, 0, 0];
  Panel@Grid[{{
      Grid@Table[
        With[{sym = sym},
         {Style[sym, FontColor -> Dynamic[color[sym]], 15], 
          ColorSlider[Dynamic[color[sym]]]}
         ]
        ,
        {sym, symbols}
        ]
      ,
      Button["PreviewCell",
       CreateDocument@List@ReplacePart[data, 1 -> highlight[content]],
        Method -> "Queued", 
       ImageSize -> CurrentValue["DefaultButtonSize"]]
      }}, Alignment -> Top]
  ,
  Initialization :> (
    rule[symbol_String] := With[{
       name = symbol,
       col = color[symbol],
       val = RawBoxes[symbol]},
      (name -> 
        ToExpression@
         MakeBoxes@
          InterpretationBox[StyleBox[name, FontColor -> col], val])];

    highlight[data_] := data /. (rule /@ symbols);
    )
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. This works perfectly with my present code. As I mentioned in the question, I was looking for a way to spot a particular variable in entire code (helps a lot when troubleshooting). So I want to assign a particular style to it and then I can find its every occurrence just by looking. Can there be a more general approach for it?

Comment: I am wanting it very much . Can you give an example for that! I can modify my question accordingly if needed. I guess all the variables can be found with a `Variable` or with a proper `Head` at some `Level` (or I can put a list of them in beginning - good old fortran style). I leave that completely on you :D .

Comment: magnifico @Kuba , (=U) [this is supposed to be a jawdrop with wide eyes]