# Is there a syntax coloring type that highlights only when not in a list?

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

How do I define the syntax coloring of local variable of function `myfunc` so that it only colors the variable that is not in a `List`?

For example,

```
SyntaxInformation[myfunc] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Integrate", {2,2}}}
```

leads to the following syntax coloring:

[image]

I only want coloring like in the first line.  I don't want the coloring appearing in the second line.  In the second case, it should not be colored, and should just look like:

[image]

Comment: This is probably not what you are looking for, but you might find it interesting [How to change the font color of a variable in whole input cell](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89507/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-variable-in-whole-input-cell)

Comment: @Sumit You're right; I'm not interested in that solution.  I need something that works for a package function.

Comment: Could you explain further what is the goal? From your description I though that `z` should be colored, but it isn't.

Comment: @Kuba In the function `myfunc`, only the second argument is a local variable.  `myfunc` only takes a symbol in the second argument.  It does not take a `List` in the second argument.  Therefore, the second argument should be colored as a local variable only if it is a symbol, and not if it is a list.  In the example above, the local variable is `x` and should be colored if it appears in the second argument.  But if a `List` appears in the second argument, the `x` inside the `List` should not be colored.  How do I prevent `x` from being colored if it is in a list?

Comment: @QuantumDot understood, thanks :)

Comment: Would `SyntaxInformation[myfunc] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, {}, ___}` help for your purpose?

Comment: @mmeent I think that’s the way to go. Show that it’s a bad argument pattern in one way or another using the ArgumentsPattern.

Comment: @mmeent Yes it does covey the point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my argument for why I think this is not possible:

First, we'll gather all the [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) out there and [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) key:

```
sinfoAll =
  Association@
   ToExpression[
    Join[
     Names["*`*"],
     Names["*`*`*"]
     ],
    StandardForm,
    Function[Null,
     If[Length@OwnValues[#] > 0 || System`Private`HasOwnCodeQ[#],
      Nothing,
      # ->
       SyntaxInformation[#]
      ],
     HoldAllComplete
     ]
    ];

sinfoGood =
  DeleteCases[sinfoAll, {} | $Failed];

sinfoVals =
  GroupBy[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Values@sinfoGood, First -> Last];
```

Then looking at the `"LocalVariables"`:

```
sinfoVals["LocalVariables"]

{None, {"Manipulate", {2, \[Infinity]}, 
  "Lexical"}, {"Solve", {2}}, {"Plot", {2, 3}}, {"Plot", {2, 
   4}}, {"D", {2, \[Infinity]}}, {"Table", {2, \[Infinity]}}, \
{"Solve", {2, \[Infinity]}}, {"Integrate", {2, \[Infinity]}}, \
{"Limit", {2}}, {"Plot", {3, \[Infinity]}}, {"Plot", {2}}, \
{"Manipulate", {2}}, {"Plot", {2, \[Infinity]}}}
```

We can try each of these in turn:

```
Block[{m = 1},
  AssociationMap[
   Function[
    With[{s = ToExpression["f" <> ToString[m++]]},
     SyntaxInformation[s] = {"LocalVariables" -> #};
     {
      Style[s[x*y*z, x, y, z], "Input"],
      Style[s[x*y*z, { x, y, z}], "Input"]
      }
     ]
    ],
   sinfoVals["LocalVariables"]
   ]
  ] // Dataset
```

[image: asdasd]

And we find that the opposite of what you want seems to be possible, but what you want does not.