# Change colours of Code

Tags: front-end, color, customization

I want to change the colour of some important variables in my code. My code is quite long and sometimes I have to change these specific variables, but it is quite annoying to search them, beacause their is no contrast and it is hard to find them. Is their a possibility to change their colour?

Comment: closely related: [How to change the font color of a variable in whole input cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89507/5478)

Answer (score 16):

Define a new *type of symbol* (context) called *highlight*,

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"SymbolContextStyles" -> {"highlight`" -> 
      Green}}]

AppendTo[$ContextPath, "highlight`"];
```

and **before** those *important variables* (symbols) appear for the first time, tell Mathematica to add them to the highlight context (e.g. `var1` and `var2`). They will be green everywhere.

```
highlight`var1; 
highlight`var2;
```

The method was posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6136694), and it is explained at length therein.